# How to display the word count with respect to word length (serially, i.e in an orderly fashion) using Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic, counting

Here, I am using dictionary to segregate the key and the values to display the word length and the count involved with the specific text file. But here, I wanted the output to display the word length serially from 1 to N (in one column) and the corresponding count (in adjacent column) associated with it.

Using `dict()=dict.get()+1` I was successful to display both word length and word count, but it does not print serially as I want to display the word count to be **0** for the word length which does not exist in the text file.

For example: -
for maximum word length of 5, and word length 4 doesn't exist, it should still show 4 serially in the word length column with the count as 0 in the count column besides it.

*I am a Robot*

```
Word Length      Word Count
 1                 2
 2                 1
 3                 0
 4                 0
 5                 1
```

Preferred not to use counter package or even regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `map` and a dictionary comprehension:

```
s = 'I am a Robot'
l = list(map(len, s.split()))
print({k: l.count(k) for k in range(1, max(l) + 1)})
```